# Are accepting tips haram or halal?

Tags: sharia

By tips I mean money you get from people who you are giving a service to. I would like to know the answer because i am confused on this topic. thank you.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what makes you think it may be haram?

Comment: You see like, would it be begging or not because it is kind of like asking for money, but at the same time you are providing a service. For example, in some cultures waiters get tipped or other professions or they may have a full business based on getting tips from other people.

Comment: Afaik, a service provider doesn't explicitly ask for tips. It is the prerogative of the customer to tip the service provider or not. To me it is more like a gift or bonus for giving great service. Hope someone answers you with an Islamic daleel too.

Answer (score -1):

There is nothing haram about accepting tips. Its simply a gift that someone is giving you for your service.

Comment: Be reminded of Quranic verse 16:116, according to which we cannot simply say something is Halal or Haram without a proof. Kindly provide one